# Why does TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10); get called before code that is infront of it?

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, wait

```
    package me.tykutcher.text.gui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestPane extends JPanel {


    public boolean sleeper = false;
    public boolean sleeper2 = false;
    public boolean sleeper3 = false;
    public boolean sleeper4 = false;
    public boolean sleeper5 = false;
    public boolean sleeper6 = false;
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString("Loading", 10, 23);
        g.drawRect(60, 13, 175, 10);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(61, 14, 25, 9);
        sleeper = true;
        if(sleeper == true){ //why do all of the delays run before adding the string, adding the rectangle, and filling the rectangle
            try {
                //delay for 10 seconds
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }}
        sleeper = false;
        g.fillRect(87, 14, 25, 9);
        sleeper2 = true;
        if(sleeper2 == true){
            try {
                //delay for 10 seconds
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        sleeper2 = false;
    }
      public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(250, 37);
        }

    }
```

Above is the class that I want the 10 second delay (just testing).
Below is the class that makes the JFrame GUI that I am running the above code in

```
package me.tykutcher.text.gui;
```

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class textGui {

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Loading... ");  
    frame.add(new TestPane());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

If i comment out the wait commands, the code all runs at once, eventually, i will have a notify or boolean way of completing this as my gui will actually be doing stuff

Comment: It doesn't. You should not sleep in this method at att.

Answer (score 1):

You painted shapes before the sleep but, you will only see them when the `paintComponent` method completes, and that's after the sleep.

If you want to draw some shapes, then have time pass, then draw some more, you need to make the time pass outside the `paintComponent` method (maybe with `javax.swing.Timer`) and decide what to paint each time `paintComponent` is called.

Answer (score 1):

thread.sleep doesn't work here because it prevents Swing from executing its necessary functions. As a result, Swing isn't able to complete paintComponent and output your loading bar until both sleep timers run out. As Jonathan mentioned above, the easiest solution is to use Javax.swing.Timer and call repaint() anytime your GUI needs to be updated.

I fixed up your loading bar using the timer function:

```
import java.awt.Color;  
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestPane extends JPanel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int xCoord = 63; // the x-coordinate value
    private int totalWidth = 26; //total width of all the bars and spaces so far

    public TestPane() {
        //Below can be rewritten to be a lambda function if you want
        Timer timer = new Timer(2500, new ActionListener() { //create a timer and actionListener - wait 2.5 seconds between each bar addition 
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                xCoord += 26; //add the length of each bar
                if (xCoord >= 167) { //make sure we don't go past the initial rectangle width
                    ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                }
                repaint(); //repaint the GUI after the timer ends
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString("Loading", 10, 23);
        g.drawRect(62, 13, 131, 10);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        int temp = xCoord; //temp variable that let's us iterate over the length of the bar without affecting the x-coordinate
        while(temp >= 63){
            g.fillRect(temp, 14, totalWidth-1, 9);
            temp -=26;
        }
    }

   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
       return new Dimension(250, 37);
   }
}
```